# Filter urlencode with 2 Level reverse relationship

Tags: django, django-admin, django-listview

I have these `models`:

```
class Issuer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

    @property
    def investor_count(self):
        return Investment.objects.filter(offering__issuer_id=self.pk).count() or 0

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Offering(models.Model):
    issuer = models.ForeignKey(Issuer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Investment(models.Model):
    offering = models.ForeignKey(Offering, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And I want to display in the `Issuer` list view the number of investments it has. This is the function I'm currently using,

```
# link investments to page
def view_investments_link(self, obj):
    count = obj.investor_count
    url = (
        reverse("admin:crowdfunding_investment_changelist")
        + "?"
        + urlencode({"issuer__id": f"{obj.id}"})
    )
    return format_html('<a href="{}">{} Investment(s)</a>', url, count)

view_investments_link.short_description = "NUMBER OF INVESTMENTS"
```

And this is how it looks:

[image]

But the line `+ urlencode({"issuer__id": f"{obj.id}"})` does not work. It changes my `url` to `http://localhost:8000/app/investment/?e=1`. Is there a way to filter `Investments` using the `issuer_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to filter *Investment* by the *issuer_id* you can simply change the *list_filter* in ModelAdmin like this

```
@admin.register(Investment)
class Investment_Register(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = ["offering__issuer__id"]
```

and then pass the id of *issuer* to URL like this
*http://localhost:8000/app/investment/?offering__issuer__id={id-issuer}*

note: if you give an error like this

```
(admin.E116) The value of 'list_filter[0]' refers to 'offering__issuer__id', which does not refer to a Field.
```

add field id minimally to your model

Comment: nice, this worked! thanks. but can I hide the list filter offering__issuer__id from the admin?

Comment: @prosy-arceno  yes you should pass a js file to your model admin class meta and in your js file you can get the id of that and then change the display property

Comment: ah that's right, thanks! appreciate it.